# Concurrent Linked Hash Set

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, set

Basically I want to create a concurrent `LinkedHashSet` which returns proper size too.

I am mainly concerned about adding and removing iterations.  Suggestions relating to implementation of set modification during iteration are also welcomed.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

//TODO still not sure
public class ConcurrentLinkedHashSet<E> extends LinkedHashSet<E>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean isUpdating = false;

    @Override
    public int size()
    {
        while (isUpdating)
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return (Integer) null;
            }
        }
        return super.size();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> arg0)
    {
        while (isUpdating)
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
        isUpdating = true;
        boolean result = false;
        result = super.addAll(arg0);
        isUpdating = false;
        notify();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized boolean add(E arg0)
    {
        while (isUpdating)
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
        isUpdating = true;
        boolean result = super.add(arg0);
        isUpdating = false;
        notify();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object arg0)
    {
        while (isUpdating)
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
        isUpdating = true;
        boolean result = super.remove(arg0);
        isUpdating = false;
        notify();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> arg0)
    {
        while (isUpdating)
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
        isUpdating = true;
        boolean result = super.removeAll(arg0);
        isUpdating = false;
        notify();
        return result;

    }
}
```

**EDIT** : Updated the code based on reviews and is available on [github](https://github.com/killer923/Java-Util-Classes/blob/master/src/main/java/com/killer923/java/util/ConcurrentLinkedHashSet.java)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several thread safety issues :

1. if `size()`, `remove()` and `removeAll()` need to `wait()`, they will throw an `IllegalMonitorStateException` since they do not hold the lock on this at the time they call `wait()`;
2. for that same reason, they may see stale values for `isUpdating`
3. if `size()` would be interrupted while waiting (supposing that gets fixed) its return statement would result in a `NullPointerException`.
4. while many threads may be waiting, only one will be notified when `isUpdating` is set to `false` again, since you call `notify()` instead of `notifyAll()`
5. operations such as `contains()` and `isEmpty()` may see stale values since they are not properly synchronized.
6. when interrupted all overridden methods violate the `Set` contract.
7. the interrupted flag is cleared upon interruption since the InterruptedException is caught and the state is not set to interrupted again.
8. not strictly a problem, but you synchronize on this. This means third party code locking on your `Set` will influence its behavior. It is preferrable to lock on a private Object.

I'm not sure what you mean exactly by 'proper size'.

Also, I think that if you properly implement this, you'll basically end up with the same behavior as what you'd get from `Collections.synchronizedSet(new LinkedHashSet())`

Comment: `point 1` : will add under synchronized blocks. `p3` : can return 0/-1.`p4`: no point in notifying all since ultimately only one would be active.`p5`: I understand it and intend to use only `size()` for now.`p6`: I believe they implement the `Set` interface since they properly override the methods in `LinkedHashSet` class.`p7`: can you elaborate.`p8`: that is the cost.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia `p4` sure, only one would be active, but this is no reason to make all the others wait forever! `p7` you're simply swallowing the interrupt, instead of calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt` so that some other piece of code in the same thread could handle it later

Comment: @maaartinus : `p4` since all the threads changing `isUpdating` will call notify, won't `notify` and `notifyAll` exhibit same behaviour?

Comment: Not all threads waiting are threads that will change `isUpdating`.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Imagine single thread starting `add()` and N threads calling `size()` and going to `wait()`. When the first one finishes, one waiter will be notified.

Comment: Btw. there's a thing called [extract method](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html), so you don't have to repeat the `while (isUpdating) {...}` loop again and again.

Answer (score 2):

Naming: I think concurrent means thread safe without locks, what you are doing is SynchronizedLinkedHashSet.